# Como hacer un cast de un float a void* y viceversa en C?

Tags: c

Buenas, tengo un problema en C, quiero hacer un cast de un float a un void* para posteriormente en otra funcion castearlo de void* a float, el problema reside en que me esta imprimiendo 0,0. A que se debe?

```
char * i = "1.22";
float numeroFlotante = (float) strtod(i,NULL); //Hace un cast de un char* a float
insertarInstruccion(&numeroFlotante, 3); //3 se refiere al tipo de dato, en este caso float.

void insertarInstruccion(void* valor, int tipo){
//ACA INSERTA ESTE DATO Y OTROS EN UNA ESTRUCTURA (PILA).

} 

void imprimirPila(){
    struct Pila *temp = pPila;
    while (temp != NULL){
        if(temp->tipo == 0){ //Si el tipo es 0 es int
            int z = (int) temp->dato;
            printf("%i\n", z);
        }
        else if(temp->tipo == 3){ //ACA ME IMPRIME 0,0.
            float valor = *(float*) &temp->dato;
            printf("%f\n",valor);
        }
        else{
            printf("%s\n", (char*) temp->dato);
        }
        temp = temp->sig;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa que no estas casteando la estructura de manera correcta

```
float valor = *(float*) &temp->dato;
```

Lo que estas haciendo ahi es obtener la direccion de memoria donde se encuentra el atributo  llamado "dato" despues lo conviertes a un puntero de tipo flotante y por ultimo accedes al contenido de esa conversion.

Lo que deberias haber hecho seria esto

```
float valor = *((float*)(temp->dato));
```

Para comprender el contexto me realizado este pequeno ejemplo basado en tu codigo publicado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef  struct{
    void* dato;
    int tipo;
}Objeto;


void insertarInstruccion(Objeto* pObjeto, void* valor, int tipo){
    pObjeto->dato=valor;
    pObjeto->tipo=tipo;
}


int main()
{
    Objeto* pObjeto= malloc(sizeof(Objeto));

    char * i = "1.22";
    float numeroFlotante = strtof(i,NULL);

    //casteamos el numero a void* y lo asignamos al struct
    insertarInstruccion(pObjeto,(void*)(&numeroFlotante),3);

    //realizamos el proceso inverso
    float valor= *((float*)(pObjeto->dato));
    printf("El valor es %f\n",valor);

    return 0;
}
```

Espero te ayude ha resolver tus dudas ya que el objeto de tipo struct es utlizado como puntero y se le reserva memoria de forma dinamica lo cual te podria servir para tu estructura de tipo pila.

PD: No olvides liberar la memoria usando la funcion free.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Me sirvió a la perfección.